# Sample python code for android: Login dialog with username and pasword

Tags: android, python, sl4a

sl4a does come with a sample getPassword, but I want to see if I can get a simply popup login box that has both Login username and Password. I have been trying to search a lot for this but cannot find how to do this in python. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the UiFacade on the [ApiReference](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference). There are for example `dialogCreateInput` and 
`dialogCreatePassword`.

Comment: I went to that site before, but it doesn't tell me how to have both the email login and password on the same popup (I messed around with it a bunch but wasn't able to get it going)